# Why do keyboard and letters not match in NetBeans?

Tags: php, netbeans, ide

I am a beginner programmer trying to learn PHP, but when I installed NetBeans the entire IDE produces garbled letters (ie. all the letters I type don't correspond to the ones on the keyboard) for all of my applications. For example I tried to type "/" but instead it produces ",". Anyone can tell me what is wrong with it? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Ensure you have got the right keyboard layout setup on your OS: http://forums.netbeans.org/post-8197.html

Answer (score 12):

Use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> key combination, that should switch the keyboard layout.

Answer (score 1):

Your keyboard layout is probably not in the language you desire.  Ensure your keyboard layout matches within the OS.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried using "shift+ctrl" to change keyboard layout, but it doesn't work...

Comment: I am using Windows 7, the default OS language is Chinese. Thanks.

Comment: Try this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964651.  As long as you're certain the keyboard layout you have selected is correct, you can try restarting the application, or even attempt a system reboot.

Comment: I tried restarting the application and the windows system... not working :(